# Junit test case with Mockito

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock, springmockito

I am creating junit test cases for my project. I have the below code, where I would like to create a mock,

```
String propertyFilePath = System.getProperty("path.to.properties"); 
Resource propertyFile = new FileSystemResourceLoader().getResource(propertyFilePath);
Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(propertyFile);
```

I am using junit and mockito-core jar. I tried with below code,

```
System.setProperty("path.to.properties", "dummyPathToProperties"); //invalid Path
Properties properties = mock(Properties.class);
Resource propertyFile = new FileSystemResourceLoader().getResource("dummyPathToProperties");
when(PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(propertyFile)).thenReturn(properties);
```

With above code it throws error when mocking loadProperties method. How can I mock a spring static class and return my mock properties object ?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking *static* methods requires you to go down the full nine yards and make use of PowerMock. The exact steps to mock static methods are outlined in their [documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockstatic) for example.

In essence:

- Use the @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) annotation at the class-level of the test case.
- Use the @PrepareForTest(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class) annotation at the class-level of the test case.
- Use PowerMock.mockStatic(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class) to mock all methods of this class.
- Use PowerMock.replay(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class) to change the class to replay mode.
- Use PowerMock.verify(ClassThatContainsStaticMethod.class) to change the class to verify mode.

But of course: consider **not** using PowerMock; by changing your code so that you don't have to mock the **static** call. But of course, it is kinda weird to add a wrapper around such a framework-provided static method.